# Azure App Certificate FraudDetected

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

My client has purchased a domain through my GoDaddy reseller account, and is attempting to bind it to his Azure App Certificate. The certificate never gets issued. After doing some research I found the 'Timeline' listing in Azure I see the domain verification passes, but there is a 'FraudDetected' entry with no further details. [image]

There's no further steps that I can find. How do I help my client verify himself to Azure?

Comment: Have your client contact Azure support. I would guess there's something in the domain name - "pay", "bank", etc. - that triggers a manual review.

Comment: I actually just found out my client is moderately famous. I suspect that is the root issue.